# How do I integrate Google calendar with my application?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I can add the Gmail account to be integrated with the application as follows. It comes to the Gmail confirmation page. I confirm but it still doesn't show on the calendar.

```
public ActionResult Ekle(int? ID)
{
                var uri = Request.Url.ToString();
                var code = Request["code"];
                int ID2 = Sabitler.EntegreMailID;
                Sabitler.EntegreMailID = 0;

                if (code != null && ID2 > 0)
                {
                    tbl_ProgramEntegre entegre2 = db.tbl_ProgramEntegre.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == ID2);
                    ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = Sabitler.HesapClientID,
                        ClientSecret = Sabitler.HesapSecretID
                    };
                    string path = @"C:/Orbis/Google_Auths";
                    string Url = Request.Url.Scheme+"://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Yonetim/ProgramEntegre/Ekle";
                    IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                    {
                        ClientSecrets = secrets,
                        DataStore = new FileDataStore(path),
                        Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly }
                    });
    
                    var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(entegre2.MailUserID, code, Url, CancellationToken.None).Result;
                    var oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(flow.DataStore, entegre2.MailUserID, Request["state"]).Result;
                    CalendarService calendarConnection;
                    var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, Url, Url).AuthorizeAsync(entegre2.MailUserID, CancellationToken.None);
                    var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
                    initializer.HttpClientInitializer = result.Result.Credential;
                    initializer.ApplicationName = "KurumsalAsistan";
                    calendarConnection = new CalendarService(initializer);
    
                    var el = calendarConnection.CalendarList.List().Execute();
    
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.RefreshToken))
                        entegre2.AccessToken = token.RefreshToken;
                    
                    entegre2.isIlk = true;
                    entegre2.isIzinVerildi = true;
                    entegre2.Mail = el.Items.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Primary==true).Id;
                    try
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Fonksiyonlar.HataEkle(ex);
                    }
                   
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
    
                tbl_ProgramEntegre entegre = db.tbl_ProgramEntegre.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == ID);

                if (entegre == null)
                    entegre = new tbl_ProgramEntegre();

                return View(entegre);
            }
}
```

Is that why it says unverified application?

[image]

Accessing my gmail account. Why can't I see the programs I added via the application in the calendar?